# dyld: Library not loaded when embedding a custom framework binary that uses Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I have a Swift dynamic framework target in the app for all the Networking Code. Lets call it **CustomNetworking.Framework**. There are other frameworks linked to this target with cocoa pods.

```
target 'CustomNetworking' do

    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'ObjectMapper'
    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'CryptoSwift' 
end
```

This framework has been included in **MainApp Target > General > Embedded Binaries**

The app runs fine on simulator, however when I run on the device, I get the following error

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
>     Referenced from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/277F2E26-6F13-4756-8FFA-0BB2DD3A8AE9/MyApp.app/MyApp
>     Reason: image not found

I can remove this error by including all the frameworks included in the Pods to the **MainApp Target > General > Embedded Binaries** . But is it the right way to fix it?

I thought may be if I add the **Pods_CustomNetworking.framework** into embedded binaries or copy files phase, the error might go away. But instead I started getting a different error - **"Application does not have a valid signature"** . Apparently, iOS is failing to verify the signature for Pods_CustomNetworking.framework.

So what is the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: @zaph You are right. But I need to jump through a lot of hoops to get the commonCrypto working. (let me know if you have a simple way to get the common crypto working with a Swift framework) So I just found it has the function that I need so just used it.

Comment: So, it is not an issue that encryption is ~3 orders of magnitude slower? If you are going to release this for others to use at least add a disclaimer WRT the performance penality.

Comment: @zaph Well, when you put it that way,  I will think about it.  To be honest, all I need is to do a SHA256 encryption on a string, nothing else. What would you recommend?

Comment: If all you are doing is SHA2 infrequently the performance may not be an issue. On iPhone 6S: SHA256, data length: 1000000
Common Crypto: 0.950 mSec,
CryptoSwift: 1319.806 mSec.

Comment: @zaph Thanks for letting me know that! I do it only once, for the lifecycle of the app.